# Event message: A configuration error has occurred

Tags: iis-7, asp

what this means and how I fix the error.
is new to asp

Event code: 3008

Event message: A configuration error has occurred.

Event time: 3/31/2017 6:23:48 AM

Event time (UTC): 3/31/2017 6:23:48 AM

Event ID: 362c9267d2b14cf0a545d969c99eb044

Event sequence: 4

Event occurrence: 1

Event detail code: 0

Application information:

```
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1458729462/ROOT-1-131354150275920924

Trust level: Full

Application Virtual Path: /

Application Path: D:\home\site\wwwroot\

Machine name: RD00155D320B3A
```

Process information:

```
Process ID: 6124

Process name: w3wp.exe

Account name: IIS APPPOOL\luckprize
```

Exception information:

```
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException

Exception message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\luckprize\web.config line 5)
```

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://luckprize.azurewebsites.net/luckprize/default.aspx

Request path: /luckprize/default.aspx

User host address: 85.191.220.103

User: 

Is authenticated: False

Authentication Type: 

Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\luckprize
```

Thread information:

```
Thread ID: 6

Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\luckprize

Is impersonating: False

Stack trace:    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
```

at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Compilation()
   at System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.IsBatchingEnabled(String configPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.IsBatchEnabledForDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Custom event details:

Comment: Can you give some context to all of this raw info? Does the error come up associated with a certain action? Is this a new web server or did something change?

Comment: it is a new iis server on azure and i get The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. on trying acces my website

Comment: error is her but how the h... do i fic it .....Config Source:
    <connectionStrings >
 <add name="DefaultConnection" Server=tcp:bingosjov.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=bingo;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={hyggelig75};Password={Miv270975};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30; />
    </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

First, you should sanitize your errors and configs before everyone pulls your direct site name, username, and password.

After you take care of that, this link appears to be relevant.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/02/16/system-configuration-configurationerrosexception-unrecognized-element-setting-and-other-unrecognized-elements/